# Can't make the vert.x + kotlin + gradle hot redeploy works

Tags: gradle, kotlin, vert.x

I just start looking into vert.x and downloaded an example restful project from https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/kotlin-examples/web. According to the readme, it should be able to auto-reploy when there's any file change, but it doesn't seem to work. No matter how many times I changed the main class file, it still cannot be reflected. What I've done was:

**Run the "gradlew run"**

```
C:\vertx-examples-master\kotlin-examples\web>gradlew run
:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:copyMainKotlinClasses UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
Jan 08, 2018 7:16:04 PM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.Watcher
INFO: Watched paths: [C:\vertx-examples-master\kotlin-examples\web\.\out]
Jan 08, 2018 7:16:04 PM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.Watcher
INFO: Starting the vert.x application in redeploy mode
Starting vert.x application...
58d1ec56-6d4c-4209-9fba-71cd6f54101c-redeploy
Jan 08, 2018 7:16:05 PM 
io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIsolatedDeployer
INFO: Succeeded in deploying verticle
```

**Change source file and the launcher was able to detect the changes and said it re-deployed the Verticle**

```
Jan 08, 2018 7:16:46 PM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.Watcher
INFO: Redeploying!
Stopping vert.x application '58d1ec56-6d4c-4209-9fba-71cd6f54101c-redeploy'
Application '58d1ec56-6d4c-4209-9fba-71cd6f54101c-redeploy' terminated with 
status 0
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Jan 08, 2018 7:16:47 PM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.Watcher
INFO: User command terminated with status 1
Starting vert.x application...
58d1ec56-6d4c-4209-9fba-71cd6f54101c-redeploy
Jan 08, 2018 7:16:47 PM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.Watcher
INFO: Redeployment done in 966 ms.
Jan 08, 2018 7:16:48 PM 
io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIsolatedDeployer
INFO: Succeeded in deploying verticle
```

**But indeed it's still running the old code**

My question is anything I need to do in order to make it work properly. I spent a day and browse for solution but still can't get through it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with kotlin + vertx + gradle. Very strange behavior but it seems to be a vertx bug in kotlin.

Comment: Can you open a bug report in the vertx-examples repo? Don't forget to mention it happens on Windows

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but with the help of this [file](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-guide-for-java-devs/blob/3.6/step-10/redeploy.bat) to be exact. I end with this batch file that help me to redeploy (tested on windows).

My project was named: ***testws*** and my main verticle was named: ***MainVerticle*** be sure to replace with yours owns.

**redeploy.bat**

```sh
@echo off

SET LAUNCHER="io.vertx.core.Launcher"
SET VERTICLE="juan.testws.MainVerticle"
SET CMD="gradlew classes"

call gradlew copyDependencies
call gradlew classes

java -cp  "build\dependencies\*;build\classes\kotlin\main" %LAUNCHER% run^
 %VERTICLE% --redeploy="src\main\**\*" --on-redeploy=%CMD% --launcher-class=%LAUNCHER%
```

and a gradle task added to

**build.gradle**

```
...  // rest of the file
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.default
  into 'build\\dependencies'
}
```

Almost the same version works on java, only replace "kotlin" by "java" on the file.